# BeautifulSoup returns None python selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, beautifulsoup

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
################import the chrome web driver and define the location###############
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/Users/../Downloads/cd79/chromedriver.exe')
###################################################################################

###########open the web page and print the title##############
page = driver.get("https://kjustin765.wixsite.com/website")
print(driver.title)
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(5)
while True:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    button1 = soup.find('span', class_='pWNha').text
    if 'Yes' in button1:
        driver.refresh()
    else:
        button1.click()
```

Why is the `page` being returned as `None`?
Here is the error

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'content
```

Comment: BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the correct data use `page.page_source` instead of `page.content`:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.page_source, 'html.parser')
```

---

The `.content` method comes from the `requests` library if you use it to request the page. For example:

```
import requests
page = requests.get(my_url).content
```